# In vb 6.0 how to do search a string in back direction

Tags: vb6

when you open notepad and after typing 10 line & then click on find it open a dialog box 
when we select up radio button. It find the string in upper direction. I want code in vb 6.0 to do same searching process 
i have tried this code but it find string in forward direction

```
Private Sub btnfind_Click() 

    str = InputBox("Enter string to search", "Find")
    pos = RichTextBox1.Find(str) 
    If pos <> -1 Then 
        RichTextBox1.SetFocus 
    Else 
        MsgBox "not found" 
    End If 

    btnfindnext.Enabled = True 
    btnprevious.Enabled = True 

End Sub 

Private Sub btnfindnext_Click() 

    pos = RichTextBox1.Find(str, pos + 1) 
    If pos <> -1 Then 
        RichTextBox1.SetFocus 
    Else 
        pos = RichTextBox1.Find(str, 0) 
        RichTextBox1.SetFocus 
    End If 

End Sub
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You want the InstrRev function:

*Returns a Long specifying the position of one string within another. The search starts either at the last character position or at the position specified by the start argument, and proceeds backward toward the beginning of the string (stopping when either string2 is found or when the beginning of the string1 is reached).*

[Have a look at this](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb6-string-functions) for the syntax